# Can't decrease PHP execution/timeout time

Tags: php, timeout, execution, die

I'm having an issue with the timeout/execution time using PHP. What I'm trying to do is test whether a Filemaker Database is available or not by using below script:

```
$connected = $fm->listLayouts();
if(FileMaker::isError($connected))
{
die('Error - ' . $connected->getCode() . ' ' . $connected->getMessage());
}
```

Problem is it takes the script **60sec** to show below error:

> Error - 7 Communication Error: (7) Failed to connect to 103.22.180.61 port 80: Connection timed out

**This is too long.** Is there a way to script in PHP to try connecting to the database and if it doesn't work within 10sec, just stop trying to connect and show the error (or do anything else) right away? I tried...

```
set_time_limit(10);
if(FileMaker::isError($connected))
{
die('Error - ' . $connected->getCode() . ' ' . $connected->getMessage());
}
```

But it didn't work. Still 60 sec. Any ideas on that? I did trying to research on my own for an hour already, without any success... Thank you so much!

Comment: Can't you set this in `php.ini`? -> ini_set('max_execution_time', 10); or try directly in the source.

Comment: I tried "ini_set('max_execution_time', 10);" already, but still 60 sec... I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

`max_execution_time` or `set_time_limit` purely only for PHP script. If connection to Filemaker maybe timeout set somewhere else in the Filemaker configuration.

From PHP Doc;

> Note:
>   The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows where the measured time is real.

Comment: Dear weirdo, thanks so much for your input. That makes sense. Damn, it also means I have no idea how to reduce the timeout for the Filemaker request... Is there ANY way to script something in PHP such as: "Try doing something, if nothing happened after 10 sec, just stop that and do something else?" - Sorry for my very simple way of describing it. ;-) Thank you so much again!